# Node throws "TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null" error

Tags: reactjs, npm, version

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q19o.png)

I just started  my react dev server and now node throws an

> TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

error. I checked my npm version, its v14.17.1.

Does someone have an idea what could cause the problem? The exact same setup ran yesterday without a single problem.

Full Stacktrace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
at Object.<anonymous> (node-version.js:5)
at Object../node_modules/default-resolution/node-version.js (node-version.js:10)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Object../node_modules/default-resolution/index.js (index.js:3)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Object../node_modules/last-run/index.js (index.js:7)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Object.<anonymous> (createExtensions.js:3)
at Object../node_modules/undertaker/lib/helpers/createExtensions.js (createExtensions.js:73)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Object../node_modules/undertaker/lib/series.js (series.js:8)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Object../node_modules/undertaker/index.js (index.js:10)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Object../node_modules/gulp/index.js (index.js:4)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Module.<anonymous> (Index.js:182)
at Module../src/views/User.js (User.js:253)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Module.<anonymous> (Auth.js:111)
at Module../src/routes.js (routes.js:94)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:30)
at Module../src/layouts/Admin.js (Admin.js:96)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Module.<anonymous> (API.js:16)
at Module../src/components/App.js (App.js:36)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Module.<anonymous> (Sidebar.js:278)
at Module../src/index.js (index.js:30)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
at fn (bootstrap:150)
at Object.1 (Tables.js:1797)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
at main.chunk.js:1
```

Comment: Node would also print a 'stacktrace' of where the error originated. That should provide some hints.

Comment: well yea but its in a node file...

Comment: Please show the error stacktrace or some code, otherwise it is really hard to find out why.